# How to set up working JVM options of a AWS Beanstalk Java SE application? Setting from documentation has no effect?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to increase the JVM maximum heap size of a AWS Beanstalk Java SE application, but the suggested setting in a `Procfile` from [AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-procfile.html) has no effect?

Answer (score 0):

The example from AWS doc

`web: java -jar server.jar -Xms256m`

does not work, because we have to switch the JVM options to

`web: java -Xms256m -jar server.jar`